# How to implement a hyperlink to display the logged in user?

Tags: 2007, custom-form

I have a custom SharePoint list with about 20 fields. If possible, I wanted to include a hyperlink on the display, edit, new form so when the user clicks the hyperlink, their login name is displayed in the text area.

So something like this:

```
<a onclick="__doPostBack('GetCurrent().Name');">Approve</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

For 2010:

Add this to the page in a content editor webpart, or add to the page layout

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function DoAction() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var user = web.get_currentUser();
    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var textbox = $jQuery("#ctl00_m_g_46c97b47_3773_4a68_8f4f_17d5faa8a9f2_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_...");
        textbox.val(user.get_loginName());
        //do whatever else here
    }, function() {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
} 
</script>
```

Then add a custom list action in sharepoint designer 2010, with this as the navigate url:

```
javascript:DoAction()
```

http://blog.furuknap.net/adding-custom-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010

For 2007:

Try using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score -1):

You could use this javascript trick to get the current user from the Welcome link

```
function getCurrentUser()
  {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++)
      {

    if(tags[i].innerText.substr(0,7) == 'Welcome')

          {

        return tags[i].innerText.substr(8,tags[i].innerText.length);

          } 

       }

  }
```

Be aware that in a multi lingual site the Welcome will be different :)
And that also this is just a little dirty hack
Hope this helps anyway

Comment: thanks for your input but when i tried to implement this i get the following error: An error occurred during the processing of disform1.aspx. only content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains content controls.

Comment: are you using sharepoint designer for this? if so here is some example. [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx). To troubleshoot your error will need to see the code

Comment: i appreciate your help. i need to know where to place your script on the form so it won't throw and error.

Comment: This is a very bad idea since you are tying yourself to various unknows. Is there a welcome link on the page? Is it rendered using just the innertext 'Welcome'. All in all, please never ever do this.

Comment: that is wht I said that this a ltitle dirty hack, I am not saying is best practices!